# How can I show a confirm pop-up without the image in java using JOptionPane and set the instructions for the the buttons?

Tags: java

I'd like to create a confirm pop-up in Java and for now I tried this

```
private void PopUp(String Messaggio)
{
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,Messaggio,"Vittoria",2,1,null);
}
```

but I don't know how to create it without the image(I tried with null) and how to handle the events of the two buttons and change their text.
Furthermore what does message type means?

Comment: Variables should start in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names which starts with uppercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#PLAIN_MESSAGE) to create a confirm dialog without an icon.

```
private void PopUp(String Messaggio)
{
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, Messaggio, "Vittoria",
                                  JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```